# Exporting maven dependencies to github pages for ant users

Tags: android, maven, ant, github, github-pages

We have [a project for Android on GitHub](https://github.com/octo-online/robospice) that:

- contains many submodules
- is fully mavenized and works well with maven
- produces artefacts of type jar

We found out a simple way to explain to new users how to setup their maven projects but we also need to explain it to people using ant (on Android, ant is the most common build tool). 
All what ant users will have to do is to put the jars (our artefacts and dependencies) in a specific folder of their android projects.

But how can we provide them with the jars ?

How can we export :

- all our dependencies jar artefacts
- all our transitive dependencies
- export them all to our gh-pages

Basically, every submodule should have its own folder, filled with jars, on github pages.

Any advice to achieve this would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

PS : we already deploy a [maven site](http://octo-online.github.com/robospice/site/latest/) to github pages using site-github maven plugin.

Answer (score 0):

[Maven ANT Tasks](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/index.html) is a simple way. Though perhaps not the spirit of ANT.

Comment: how could maven ant tasks be useful here ?

Comment: You just tell them to use The ANT task to download the dependencies for themselves. They need only provide the GAV coordinate and the task will pull down the transitive list and return a fileset which can e copied wherever they want